# how to print only part of the response object in the html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am sending the file path along with filename from the spring controller to the html page.
(i.e., `D:/dataStacks/myStacks/myFilename.txt` is sent from spring controller to js controller).
I want to show the complete path of the file as well as only filename on the webpage.
Please advice how can i print only filename from FILEPATH response object returned to the js controller.Any suggestions would be helpful.

js controller:

```
myApp.controller('getPathController', function ($scope, MyFilesService) {
  $scope.getFilePathAndName = function () {
    MyFilesService.getFiles().then(
      function (response) {
        $scope.filePathAndName = response; // c:/dataStacks/myStacks/myFilename.txt
      },
      function (errResponse) {
        //error
      });
  }
  $scope.getFilePathAndName();
});

//service call
myFilesService.getFiles = function () {
    var Url = myURL + '/filesPathData/getFilePath.form';
    $http.get(repUrl).then(
      function (response) {
        //return response
      }
      //return statement
    }
```

spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFilePath", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="text/plain")
public @ResponseBody String getFilePath1(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
  String FILEPATH = "c:/dataStacks/myStacks/myFilename.txt";
  File f = new File(FILEPATH);
  //logic to deal with the file
  return FILEPATH;
}
```

html:

```
<html>

<body>
  FilePath with filename : {{filePathAndName}} //logic implementation //print only the filename from above got response object
  <h1>FileName here</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

In my html page I want to print the filename taken from the response object.
`{{filePathAndName}}` contains the `D:/dataStacks/myStacks/myFilename.txt`. How can I print only filename `myFilename.txt` in the html page.

Comment: you can use split function of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple string functions/methods would suffice admirably:

```
var string = 'c:/dataStacks/myStacks/myFilename.txt';
var fileName = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
console.log(fileName); // myFilename.txt
```

Comment: 2 notes: I wouldn't name a variable string (even though I know this is just a mockup). Also, this returns "/myFilename.txt".

Answer (score 0):

To extract the filename from the path, try this:

```js
var filename = "c:/dataStacks/myStacks/myFilename.txt".split("/").slice(-1)[0];
console.log(filename);
```

So, you need to change the expression `{{filePathAndName}}` to `{{filePathAndName}}.split("/").slice(-1)[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

A handy function here is `lastIndexOf()`. This grabs the last instance of the `/` and `substring` sets `$scope.filePathAndName` to that last portion you're looking for. Here's a quick mockup of what that looks like:

```js
var temp = "C:/folder/project/other/myFile.txt";
    var index = temp.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    console.log(temp.substring(index));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, split the path from slash and get the last element of the array.

```
$scope.filePathAndName = response.split(/[/]+/).pop();
```